# Add verification page to google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to use webmaster tools for my webapp. For that i have to upload a verification page to the URL / which is a static file. I have no idea how to edit the config file so that i can upload the static file say "xyz" to URL "/". Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a programming language listed in [App Engine: Platform as a Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/), then follow the tutorial in that language.  Each tutorial includes steps to create a home page for the application and deploy it to the production environment.

If you need more help, add your language choice to this question, as well as steps you have performed so far.

**Edit**: the [Static file handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) section of [Python Application Configuration with app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig) says under the 'Static file pattern handlers' heading that `static_files` and `upload` entries are required in app.yaml, for example:

```
- url: /xyz$
  static_files: xyz
  upload: xyz
```

You will probably need to create a separate entry for each such file, because the files are not grouped in a directory.

Comment: my language is python

Comment: the instructions instruct to put static files in a directory. I dont want that.I want to put it in root folder